# OpensearchJs MultiSearch request body

Tags: javascript, json, opensearchjs, multisearch

I am using the [opensearchJs](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-js/blob/main/USER_GUIDE.md) client to send requests. When looking through the docs for opensearchJs there are no examples on how a multisearch query body should be structured in order to use the client correctly.

Does the user need to format the body such that each query needs to be on a single line as defined [here](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/api-reference/multi-search/) or does the client do this formatting if given a normal array of json objects?

Also, if each object needs to be on a single line, could this be achieved by simply doing a `JSON.stringify` on the object, as in:

```
[
  JSON.stringify({}),
  JSON.stringify({
      "from": 0,
      "limit": 5,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  )
]
```

i.e. do I need to format the body to

```
[
  {},
  {"from": 0, "limit": 5, "query": {"query": {"bool": {...}}}}
]
```

Or could I pass in

```
[
  {},
  {
    "from": 0,
    "limit": 5,
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
]
```